# Windows 7 Device Stage

Tags: windows, winapi

Can anyone please provide some information on Device Stage for Windows 7 from a developers perspective? That is how a developer needs to develop his software for a device in order to expose it through Windows 7 Device Stage? Please pardon me if I am wrong somewhere...  I know very little about Device Stage.

Thanks,
Sourabh

Answer (score 1):

Get the [Device Experience Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/DeviceExperience/Dev-Kit.mspx)